# Toggling animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, animation

In the following piece of code I use the same trick three times. But cannot figure out how to write a common function that will do it for all of them. I know there is a toggle method in jQuery that does something similar but in this situation I wasn't able to get it do the job for me, so I wrote this:

```
// fallback for ie
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    var flag = true;
    $(".right-arrow").click(function () {
        if (flag) {
            $(".slider-frame").animate({ left: "-130px" }, 1000);
            flag = false;
        }
        else {
            $(".slider-frame").animate({ left: "236px" }, 1000);
            flag = true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
    // more smooth CSS3-animation with move.js
else {
    var flag = true;
    $(".right-arrow").click(function () {
        if (flag) {
            move(".slider-frame").set("left", -130).duration("1s").end();
            flag = false;
        }
        else {
            move(".slider-frame").set("left", 236).duration("1s").end();
            flag = true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

// eye that make passwords visible
var state = true;
$(".login-form form").append("<div class='eye'></div>");
$(".eye").click(function () {
    if (state) {
        $("#password").attr("type", "text");
        $(".eye").css("background-position", "0 -49px");
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#password").attr("type", "password");
        $(".eye").css("background-position", "0 0");
        state = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: First off, before trying to DRY up your code, I'd suggest applying some more important concepts. For once, I'd suggest using proper feature detection instead of sniffing the `appName`. IE10 supports CSS3 animations, while old non-IE browsers do not.

Comment: You need to place your code into some functions. That you can reuse your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to DRY it up:

```
var flag = true,
    isIE = navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer";

$(".right-arrow").click(function () {
    if (isIE) {
        $(".slider-frame").animate({ left: flag ? "-130px" : "236px" }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        move(".slider-frame").set("left", flag ? -130 : 236).duration("1s");
    }    
    flag = ! flag;
    return false;
});
```

---

As pointed out by @FabrícioMatté, you should [use feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264899/detect-css-transitions-using-javascript-and-without-modernizr) instead of browser sniffing.

---

**P.S.** You should also learn to [cache your selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea about some things you can do to make it leaner.

For each item that needs a click event, create an Immediately Executing Function.   This will allow you to give local scope and not have a bazillion variables in the same scope to keep track of.

next, see what comonalities you can find for each IEF, and bring them to the top of the IEF.

I never like to attach event handlers via if/then statements.  I'd rather figure out what I need to attach via if/then/whatever and only then attach.

Here's a start for ".slider-frame".

```
(function(){
    var selector = ".slider-frame",
        clickmethod, 
        flag = true, 
        measures = [236, -130]; 
    //this could be handled better, but whatever, fixing this wasn't the request
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        clickmethod = function(){
            var value = measures[Number(flag)] + "px";
            $(selector).animate({ left: value }, 1000);
            flag = !flag;
        }
    }
    // more smooth CSS3-animation with move.js
    else {
        clickmethod = function(){
            var value = measures[Number(flag)];
            move(selector).set("left", value).duration("1s").end();
            flag = !flag;
        }
    }
    $(".right-arrow").click(clickmethod);
})();
```

Edit: Joseph Silber's point about caching "selectors" (or rather any reference to `$(something)`) is also a good point but if anything referred to by such an expression is replaced, your cached "selector" will no longer be valid.  Furthermore, it's not clear to me if `move(selector)` can be cached or not, so I just left it be.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting how you use the conversion of boolean to number. It's a good idea!